# Add date column that based upon other date column SQL BQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column of dates in my table (referred as org_day).
I try to add a new column that represent the day after, that is
day_after = org_day + day (or 24 hours) (for all rows of org_day)

From what I've read, the DATE_ADD function of SQL does not
work on the entire column, so trying to do something like:
DATE_ADD (org_day, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) or
DATE_ADD (DATE org_day, INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
do not work.
The usual examples that do work look like:
DATE_ADD (DATE '2019-12-22', INTERVAL 1 day),
But I want to perform this operation on the entire column,
not on a constant date.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

To update the entire column, you need to set everything on that column. Try this, hope it solved ur problem...

UPDATE table_name SET column_name = DATE_ADD(var, interval);

Comment: Thanks! Where do I put this UPDATE  line? In a new query (after with table AS ?), In the same query it didn't work from what I tried so far.

Comment: new sql query on ur db

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  mydataset.mytable AS
SELECT
  org_day,
  DATE_ADD(org_day, INTERVAL 1 day) day_after
FROM
  mydataset.mytable;
```

> This above statement will modify the the existing table by adding a new column, without deleting exiting data.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*, date_add(org_day, interval 1 day) as day_after
    from t;
```

If you always want the new column to be in synch with existing column, then a view ensures that the data is consistent.  The value is calculated *when you query the data*.